# Extra character added to URL

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Ok so I am working on [this](http://geetasfoods.com) site (using wordpress), here's the thing; it's only a small aesthetic feature but the main reason I'm asking this question is to discover the cause. If you go to [this](http://geetasfoods.com/recipes/) section of the site you'll notice that you don't actually get sent to the link above, instead of

/recipes/ you go to /recipesa/ which isn't (as far as I'm aware) set up as an automatic redirect, what's more in the back end of the site the code clearly points to /recipes :

```
/* Taken from the navigation bar code */

<li><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/recipes">Recipes</a></li>
```

Anyone know why this happens? Cheers

Comment: Try the full link without the <php>. Full on html <a tag> and see if it still does the same thing

Comment: Even when manually typing in the address, it still loads as that so @Joe seems like the most likely problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highly likely that your Recipes page was originally called "Recipesa" by accident and you renamed it, but the permalink didn't change because Wordpress doesn't do that.

Go to Edit Pages in WP-Admin, then edit the Recipes page and check the permalink (directly below the page title textbox).

Comment: After looking at the site, I am going to go with this possibility as well.

Comment: Wanted to see if it was the right answer first :P which is why I said "Possibility" but here you go +1 :)